# VS Code Java appears to be compiling on every keystroke

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I have been using VS Code with Java for a few months learning the basics. I am not able to update the app myself it is controlled by the company I work for.

Last Friday the IDE seemed to be trying to compile/build on every single key stroke. If I were to simply type something like:

```
int x;
```

this will generate a Problem on:

- i is not defined
- in is not defined
- int declared with no variable name.
- declaration missing ';'

These 'problems' can take minutes for VS Code to catch up on and realise that statement is valid. There is no intellisense possible either with this so typing 'x.' anything raises more errors. I have searched for this issue and tried turning off auto save, build on save, java.autobuilder to off and the issues remain.

The Java Build Status has a wheel constantly turning and is constantly outputting:

4c8c5808 Building [Done]

84f654df Building [Done]
Over and over again.

VS Code Version 1.60.0

JDK 16.0.2

Only installed the Microsoft Java Extensions.

Comment: Don't tag Visual Studio for VS Code questions!

Comment: Apologies, it is removed now. I thought I had deleted it. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Seems somthing wrong with extension, can you [reset vs code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/setup/setup-overview#_how-can-i-do-a-clean-uninstall-of-vs-code) and reinstall java extension?

Comment: Hi @MollyWang-MSFT , I cannot uninstall the application, or even delete folders/files, the company locked it down. I did uninstall every extension and reinstall them to the same issue. I will have to get someone to uninstall it for me I think. I've not found this issue anywhere online. I'll raise an internal ticket and see what can be done.

Comment: @RossC. Ok, hope reinstallation fix your question.

Comment: @MollyWang-MSFT it turns out the laptop was completely broken and the Java extension from the Microsoft site was failing installation. I have a new laptop now and after installing the extensions and the add on everything works great!

Comment: @RossC. That's great! Happy Coding:)

Answer (score 2):

To correct this behavior, you will need to turn the Visual Studio Code auto-save feature. You can find this setting under File > AutoSave.